# SQL: How to find rows by filtering on a value within an XML column

Tags: xml, t-sql, xpath, sql-server-2012, xquery

I have a field having an XML data type, below is the example of XML data that I saved in that field. Now, I want to select the data having "1" inside `<SiteId>` tags by using the query below but no result comes out.

```
SELECT [SettingsID]
      ,[XMLData]
FROM Settings
Where [XMLData].exist('/Settings/SiteId/text()[contains(.,"1")]') =1 


XMLDATA sample

<Settings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SiteId>1</SiteId>
  <ModuleId xsi:nil="true" />
  <TabId xsi:nil="true" />
  <Version>0</Version>
</Settings>
```

Anyone has an idea on this?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh, ms sql 2012

Comment: @crisgomez I just tested your query against my mockup table (see the answer) and it seems to work... Be aware, that `contains` would find any text including a `1` in any position

Comment: @crisgomez I just reworded your title - please check this and rollback the changes, if I did not get this correctly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The title of your question is - assumably - misleading...

I think you are not looking for a *full text search*, but rather for the appropriate `XQuery` to find entries with given conditions.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(SettingsID INT IDENTITY, XMLData XML);
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES
 (N'<Settings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SiteId>1</SiteId>
  <ModuleId xsi:nil="true" />
  <TabId xsi:nil="true" />
  <Version>0</Version>
</Settings>')
,(N'<Settings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SiteId>2</SiteId>
  <ModuleId xsi:nil="true" />
  <TabId xsi:nil="true" />
  <Version>0</Version>
</Settings>');
```

--The query tests, if there is any `<SiteId>`, whose `text()` is `1`

```
SELECT[SettingsID]
      ,[XMLData]
FROM @mockupTable
Where [XMLData].exist('/Settings/SiteId[text()="1"]') =1;
```

You can introduce the `1` to the query simply by using `sql:variable("@SomeIntVariable")` instead of the `"1"`

```
DECLARE @id INT=2;
SELECT[SettingsID]
      ,[XMLData]
FROM @mockupTable
Where [XMLData].exist('/Settings/SiteId[text()=sql:variable("@id")]') =1
```

### UPDATE

To create this as tolerant as possible you can use the **deep search** with `//` and the *`*:`* to omit any namespaces:

```
SELECT[SettingsID]
      ,[XMLData]
FROM @mockupTable
Where [XMLData].exist('//*:SiteId[text()="1"]') =1;
```

Comment: Thanks @Shnugo, This is working, however when I'm using the actual table this is not working. Not sure why.

Comment: @crisgomez What does "not working" mean? Error? No results? Are there namespaces you did not mention? Might the structure be different (did you not post a *full* sample)?

Comment: @crisgomez Try to set your `XPath` to `Where [XMLData].exist('//*:SiteId[text()="1"]') =1;` This will perform a *deep search* (omitting parent nodes) and ignore namespaces...

Comment: It works! Shnugo, thank you very much! By the way, what I mean of "not working" is there is no results.

Comment: @crisgomez Great! In this case I assume, that the given sample XML was somehow reduced / simplified and therefore the `XPath` did not hit.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I though the .exist() is part of full text search functionality.

Comment: I have another question, I have another field which consist of JSON data, if I am using full text search, how can I implement the code if I am searching this value "/1/"? Or is there another approach other than full text search?

Comment: @crisgomez please avoid follow-up questions... Better place a new question. Just in short: FTS is good in finding *words*. Technical expressions, such as `/1/` can be found with `LIKE '%/1/%'`. But this will not be fast... If you need more detailled answers, place a new question with sample data and some words about the row/hit counts, indexes and so on, best is to [create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks @Shnugo! Appreciate it a lot.

Comment: @Shnugo- here is the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48501210/how-to-find-rows-by-filtering-a-specific-text-using-full-text-search-in-ms-sql-2

Answer (score 0):

Mayby silly, but as i understand your problem well, this may work fine:

```
SELECT [SettingsID],[XMLData]
FROM Settings
Where [XMLData] LIKE '%<SiteId>1</SiteId>%'
```

Comment: Hi P.ejH, we have the same implementation, I changed it to full text search because of performance issues.

Comment: According to the sample code the given column is native XML. The `LIKE` would need a cast to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` first (which is quite expensive here...)

Comment: @crisgomez The correct XML query with `.exist()` is f- for sure! - faste than a full text search...